# Setting values by Socket.setReceiveBufferSize in Java, exceeding OS socket buffer limits

Tags: java, linux, sockets

I had tests to see how Java Socket.setReceiveBufferSize(int size) works when the given size exceeds socket buffer limit in Linux.

I set the following configurations to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 12582912 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 12582912 16777216
```

My simple receiver test code is as follows:

```
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(myport);
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(26777216);
System.out.println("Listening...");
Socket.client = socket.accept();

System.out.println("accepted!");
System.out.println("client.getReceiveBufferSize: " + client.getReceiveBufferSize());
try (InputStream in = client.getInputStream();) {
    byte[] input = in.readAllBytes();
    System.out.println("input length: " + input.length);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    socket.close();
}
System.out.println("DONE");
```

My sender test code is as follows:

```
Socket so = new Socket(testhost, testport);
so.setSendBufferSize(99999999);
try (OutputStream out = so.getOutputStream();) {
    byte[] b = new byte[99999999];
    Arrays.fill(b, (byte)1);
    out.write(b);
    out.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    so.close();
}
```

Test output:

```
Listening...
accepted!
client.getReceiveBufferSize: 16777216
input length: 99999999
DONE
```

I expected something like errors caused by setting "26777216" which exceeds os' limits to the socket's receive buffer size or actually receiving bytes exceeding the limits, but It worked fine. What am I missing?

*EDIT*

Something came up to my mind. If os uses its own buffer in kernel level and the os' limit settings affect the buffers' size, which do not mean "maximum receive sizes at one time", Is there a way of setting the actual maximum size of one time receive?

Comment: I think probably `readAllBytes` is reading smaller chunks consecutively under the hood as the data comes in.

Comment: See the Javadoc. Nothing there about giving range errors. The platform can adjust the requested size up or down.